# Error: cannot find symbol when running code from command line but code runs fine in vscode's debugger

Tags: java, class

I have 2 classes in the same package and directory, and when I try to run them i get the Error. at the line

```
User user1 = new User(0, list);
```

heres the exact command I'm running

```
javac src/main/java/CS_214_Project.java
and
java src/main/java/CS_214_Project.java
```

CS_214_Project class

```
package pa4;

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
public class CS_214_Project{

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>();
    list.add(2.0);
    list.add(3.0);
    list.add(2.0);
    System.out.println(calcMean(list));
    System.out.println(calc_sdv(list));
    User user1 = new User(0, list);
    System.out.println(user1.getValues());
  }

  public static void Read_Names(){

  }

  public static void read_Values(){
    
  }

  public static double calcMean(ArrayList<Double> list){
    double total = 0;
    for (Double double1 : list) {
      total += double1;
    }
    return total / list.size();
  }

  private static String calc_sdv(ArrayList<Double> list){
    if(list.size() <= 1){
      return "UNDEFINED";
    }

    Double mean = calcMean(list);
    Double sum = 0.0;
    for(Double l : list){
      sum += (l - mean) * (l - mean);
    }

    return Double.toString(Math.sqrt(sum / (list.size() - 1)));
  }
}
```

User Class

```
package pa4;

import java.util.*;

public class User{
    int userNumber;
    ArrayList<Double> Values= new ArrayList<Double>();

    public User(int number, ArrayList<Double> list){
        this.userNumber = number;
        this.Values = list;
    }

    public void setUserNumber(int userNumber) {
        this.userNumber = userNumber;
    }

    public void setValues(ArrayList<Double> values) {
        Values = values;
    }

    public int getUserNumber() {
        return userNumber;
    }

    public ArrayList<Double> getValues() {
        return Values;
    }

    public void addValue(double value) {
        this.Values.add(value);
    }

    public void removeValue(double value) {
        this.Values.remove(value);
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return this.Values.size();
    }
}
```

[image: heres the code configuration]

I've tried moving the classes between directories, removing them from a package, and remaking the files, but nothing has fixed this error yet.

Comment: Please show the exact command you're running

Comment: And the project configuration in vscode.